# Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data

Tags: vb.net, version, .net-assembly, mysql.data, publickeytoken

I've installed the MySQL for Visual Studio and the .NET Connector (6.8.3.0). 
I previous had the 6.7.4.0 installed. Why is it still looking for this DLL?

I get the error message form event viewer:

> Msg: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The .NET framework version that i using compile is .NET framework 3.5

I've installed the MySQL for Visual Studio and the .NET Connector 6.7.4.0. and run success before (no error occur when use 6.7.4) 
but the program need to change to version 6.8.3.0.

So I download and install again the version 6.8.3 and added it as a reference and have the Imports line, but the error occur

How to solve this kind of error , in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html), add it as a reference and import it `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient`

Comment: I've installed the MySQL for Visual Studio and the .NET Connector (6.8.3.0). I previous had the 6.7.4.0 installed. Why is it still looking for this DLL?

Comment: @HaoZheng Have you added it as a reference and have the `Imports` line? What .NET framework version are you using to compile? you need old MySQL Data versions for older .NET framework, just search for the supported versions.

Comment: I added it as a reference and have the Imports line already, 
.net compact framework 2.0 SP 2
.net compact framework 3.5
.net framework 4 multi-targeting pack
This is all .net framework that I found in my pc

  
I've installed the MySQL for Visual Studio and the .NET Connector  6.7.4.0.  and run success before (no error occur when use 6.7.4), but the program need to change to version 6.8.3.0



So I download and install again the version 6.8.3 and added it as a reference and have the Imports line, but the error occur.

Thanks your help xD

Comment: @HaoZheng I'm not talking about the .NET framework installed in your PC, I want to know what .NET framework version are you using to compile your project. You can find this in your projects properties -> Compile - > Advanced Compile Options

Comment: ops sorry ,  the .NET framework  version that i using compile is .NET framework 3.5

Comment: @HaoZheng Have you solved your problem? The compatible MySQL Data version for .net framework 3.5 is version 6.3.*

Comment: Hi, the problem was solved, I added the code below in my app.config
thanks xD

<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D" culture="neutral"/>
    <!--bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.8.0"/-->
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.8.3.0" />
        
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>

Answer (score 0):

Go to the NuGet package manager in your project, search for MySQL and then add it to your project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/